# PHP Queries not working

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

This is working:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((((defect
JOIN project_testcase ON 
defect.Test_Id=project_testcase.Test_Id)
JOIN testcase ON 
defect.Test_Id=testcase.Test_Id)
JOIN project_pm ON 
project_testcase.Project_Id=project_pm.Project_Id)
JOIN employee ON 
employee.Emp_id=project_pm.Emp_id)
```

However, this does not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((((defect
JOIN project_testcase ON 
defect.Test_Id=project_testcase.Test_Id)
JOIN testcase ON 
defect.Test_Id=testcase.Test_Id)
JOIN project_pm ON 
project_testcase.Project_Id=project_pm.Project_Id)
JOIN employee ON 
employee.Emp_id=project_pm.Emp_id)
WHERE Project_Id LIKE '%$categ%'
```

As I have used JOIN tables and joined using `Project_Id`. Is that the error?

Comment: First thing to do is format / indent your code properly. You might even find the problem that way.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Is the error message or unexpected behaviour produced by the 2nd query classified?

Comment: I think Matt's answer should help you with any error you might get. It also looks like `$categ` is a variable, in which case you should concatenate it's value, now you just use its name (`'%' + $categ + '%'
`). If you can, use prepared statements, which is much better still.

Comment: When you post questions on forums it helps considerably if you post the error messages you receive instead of leaving people to guess.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do to troubleshoot this is to paste it into an SQL formatter. This will help find syntax errors and could help you see a logic error. I would recommend [freeformatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/sql-formatter.html#ad-output).

Second you can get rid of the parenthesis.

## The Fix

You need to specify what table to get the Project_Id in the WHERE because it is in multiple tables, but for clarity I would always specify what table it comes from.

```
select
   *   
from
   defect   
join
   project_testcase         
      on   defect.Test_Id=project_testcase.Test_Id       
join
   testcase      
      on   defect.Test_Id=testcase.Test_Id    
join
   project_pm   
      on   project_testcase.Project_Id=project_pm.Project_Id    
join
   employee   
      on   employee.Emp_id=project_pm.Emp_id    
where
   project_testcase.Project_Id like '%$categ%'
```

Comment: If my answer helped fix your issue, could you make it as the accepted answer @AbhinavChanana

Answer (score 0):

`Project_Id` in the where clause is ambiguous, you need to define it as you have done on your joins ie `WHERE project_pm.Project_Id like '%$categ%'`

Answer (score 0):

In the where clause of the 2nd query you need to tell the rdbms exactly which Project_Id field you want to filter on, since multiple tables contain the Project_Id field, e.g. `project_pm.Project_Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting by removing all those unnecessary parenthesis, formatting and aliases reveals a fairly simple query underneath.

```
select * --This should really be the columns you actually need instead of all of them
from defect d
join project_testcase ptc on d.Test_Id = ptc.Test_Id
join testcase t on d.Test_Id = t.Test_Id
join project_pm p on ptc.Project_Id = p.Project_Id
join employee e on e.Emp_id = p.Emp_id
where p.Project_Id like '%$categ%'
```

Of course this begs the question of why do you have text like that in a column named Project_Id? That does not look like a project id to me. And since you are using a leading wildcard you have a nonSARGable query so you have eliminated the ability of index seeks on that column.